# AngularJs 1.3 multi value separated by enter in textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm searching for a way on how i can add multiple values inside a textbox, something like a tag entry.
I have an app in which i can add multiple users on an event and i would like to be able when hit enter or click on some user to add it as a tag inside that textbox. Best example is stackoverflow tags area. 
Any suggestions, resources or ideas?
Thank you all.

PS. i've worked a little with angular 2 and i remember that there was something provided by a vendor, but could not find something similar for angularjs

Comment: You can use the [`ng-list` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList)

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular's build in [`ng-list` directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngList):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.tags = ["some tag", "some other tag"];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="tags" ng-list />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{ tag }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput): it's *the* Tags input directive for AngularJS. Here is a code sample:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
<p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
```

And you'll find it working in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RHm7H2?p=info)